# Twilio Call Status

Tags: twilio

How do I know whether or not a call is answered?

For StatusCallback, I can set the following values:

- initiated
- ringing
- answered
- completed

When Twilio sends me statuses, I don't see a value for "answered" what I see are the following:

- no-answer
- busy
- completed
- initiated
- failed

I'm wondering why there is no status returned for:

- answered

though I'm setting "answered" as one of the values for StatusCallback.

What confuses me is that Twilio sends "Completed" irrespective of whether or not the call was answered or not.

I need a definite status for the call being answered. If the call is not answered then I need to retry again later or build a business logic around it.

When the call is not answered, then I get "not-answered".

When the call is answered, then I get "completed", but "completed" does not necessarily mean the call was actually answered assuming that the call went to the voicemail box or something.

On a side note, I am also setting the "IfMachine" parameter in the call request. Though I know that it is an experimental feature, I get the call status as "completed" as in this case, my expectation is "not-answered".

How do I know if the call was actually answered?

Comment: That seems really strange that you are not getting the "answered" webhook. It should work. I'd advise getting in touch with the Twilio support team on help@twilio.com and sending them some call Sids where the call was answered but you did not receive the "answered" callback.

Comment: Will do... Thanks... Yes, none of the time I got the "answered" webhook returned.

Comment: @philnash I just got a note from Twilio support that the status for "answered" is "in-progress". Here is the note: I'm sorry for the confusion on the statuses. The key is that there is a difference in the call event names and the call status names. While there is an event called "answered", there is no status called "answered." Instead you'll receive "in-progress" as the status when the call is answered.

Comment: I dont see no-answered status.

Answer (score -1):

Megan, also from Twilio!

Just wanted to clear a few things up here. You mention using `StatusCallback` which expects a URL. The `answered` value is actually set using `StatusCallbackEvent` as you can see [here in the docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls).

I don't know what language you're using but an example in Python (you can find other languages on that docs page):

```
# Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
account_sid = "YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID"
auth_token  = "YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN"
client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)

call = client.calls.create(
    url="http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml",
    to="+14155551212",
    from_="+18668675309",
    method="GET",
    status_callback="https://www.myapp.com/events",
    status_callback_method="POST",
    status_events=["initiated", "ringing", "answered", "completed"],
)
print call.sid
```

And a final note about using `IfMachine`. For the time being, we actually recommend that you use Twilio's `<Gather>` verb to detect if a human picks up as explained [in this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768186/initiating-outbound-calls-with-twilio/33769648#33769648).

Hope this helps!